# Is it possible to ask for a server to *not* send "Certificate Request" in its "Server Hello"?

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, energy

I am working on using different security protocols on a constrained device (energy-wise) and TLS (1.0) is one of them. To reduce the number of bytes transmitted I would like the server I'm talking to to not send a list of client certificates in the Server Hello message. As I'm performing one-way SSL I believe I have have no need for the "Certificate Request" field which represent a sizeable amount of data (around 3 KB) I'd like to remove from the transmission.

Is it possible as a client (maybe in the 'Client Hello') to ask the server not to send these information or is it a server-side decision only ? All my reading so far seems to indicate I can't do that as a client but I'm asking the community if you have more insights on that matter.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Client can't (directly) request anything about server's CertRequest except that below TLS1.3 _if_ client offers and server agrees to an _anonymous_ ciphersuite then server does not authenticate at all and cannot request client authenticate at all. However anonymous suites are usually insecure and not supported or allowed. Do you want server to omit CertRequest entirely, or to send CertRequent with an empty list of CAnames? The latter is allowed by protocol, but whether server supports it depends on the software or middleware used and its configuration. ...

Comment: ... If server supports multiple 'virtual' or 'logical' hosts, as many do today, client _can_ specify which virtual host it wants using ServerNameIndication extension, and server might be able to have one virtual host that handles CertRequest as you desire.

Comment: Hi @dave_thompson_085, thanks for the reply ! If possible I would like the server to omit CertRequest altogether but an emply list of CA names would also be better than what is done at the moment where I just receive 3 KB worth of CA names.
As I don't find any information on the server documentation regarding the ServerNameIndication extension, it seems unlileky it handles multiple logical hosts. Thanks for your answer !